# Add obj file to linker input with cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, cmake

I have a cmake project that needs to link to a library that contains some .lib files and a .obj file. I've found some clues to how to link to a .obj file, but most solutions seem very complex.

All I really want to do is tell cmake to add the .obj file to the linker input in my Visual Studio project.

I tried linking it as I am doing with normal lib files:

```
target_link_libraries(Foo C:/a.lib C:/b.lib C:/c.obj)
```

However when I check the linker input in the generated VS project, cmake has removed the full-path and appended .lib to the obj file:

```
C:/a.lib
C:/b.lib
c.obj.lib
```

What's the simplest way of getting this result:

```
C:/a.lib
C:/b.lib
C:/c.obj
```

Note that this only needs to work with Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't see how the linked question is relevant?

Comment: Is this too difficult http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025541.html ?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing facing the same issue when I found your question. It is solved by the following line:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(my_project PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/link setargv.obj")
```

The link is appended to *Additional Options* in the *Command Line* Section from project's linker settings.

Comment: For some reason I had to remove the "/link" bit. So I have the following (seems to work on Visual Studio 14 2015 Winx64"). This enables shell globbing in Windows.

`set_target_properties(codexcompressionutil PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "setargv.obj")`